# Can i interchangeably use ctypes.LP_c_char and bytes object in Google client library

Tags: python, ctypes, google-speech-api

In the example of streaming from mic in Google client library: [Google streaming example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/transcribe_streaming_mic.py)

I placed a print line to print type of in_data in fill buffer callback like this:

```
def _fill_buffer(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, status_flags):
    """Continuously collect data from the audio stream, into the buffer."""
    print(type(in_data))
    self._buff.put(in_data)

    if time.time() - self._start_time > TIME_OUT:
        self.closed = True

    return None, pyaudio.paContinue
```

What i got is type: class 'bytes'

I have written a shared lib in c that pre-processing audio data then fill this data to the above callback. The type of data i received from c is: class 'ctypes.LP_c_char', can i use this interchangeably with bytes class, or i have to convert ctypes.LP_c_char to bytes(using list slicing). I don't want to convert because of streaming purpose.